How to close a third-party application if user inactivity
I have a Flutter Windows application in which an executable opens (in my case, Chrome).
After opening it, if the user remains inactive for 20 seconds, the executable should close and return to the application (which is a media player) that was already running normally in the background.
I couldn't access the executable in any way through flutter, does anyone have any ideas?

I've never done this myself, but this looks promising: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Process/killPid.html Of course it all depends on how you actually start the Chrome process, so you'll want to share that too.

But how would I monitor if the user is taking any action on the executable?

There's nothing in Flutter's process handling to do that that I know of. Not sure what you are running in Chrome, but maybe that app can post to an API that your Flutter code can then monitor?
